# Cells are too small and I can't see the code I write

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am starting using google colab, I am learning so I am watching a lot of videos. I see that in all videos cells are large and you can see the code easy. But when I open a new notebook or someone shares to me one notebook I see the cells very small and centered. I can't see what I writing. Please help!

[look how the cells are too small](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQVjK.png)

I have search in Internet about this but I cant find any solution. Ask ChatGPT about it and nothing works.